# Get rows if one or the other or both fields match

Tags: mysql

I need to fetch promotions by location where I have the following logic:

```
City = Oslo, Country = No : True  
City = '', Country = No : True  
City = Bergen, Country = No : False
```

The query I have to so far is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM promotion
WHERE date_start <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
AND date_end >= CURDATE()
AND fk_countryID = 'NO'
order by date_start ASC
```

This returns 5 rows.
- Once city is blank.
- One city is Bergen

Wanted result: 4 rows where one city is blank.

I also tried this:

```
SELECT id, name, city, fk_countryID, date_start, date_end
FROM promotion
WHERE date_start <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
AND date_end >= CURDATE()
AND city = '' || city = 'Oslo'
AND fk_countryID = 'NO'
order by date_end ASC
```

This does return all rows where city is either blank or 'Oslo' and country id is 'no', but it also returns rows outside the date constraints.

How can I achieve this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you found the answer, please post it as a proper answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer:

```
SELECT id, name, city, fk_countryID, date_start, date_end
FROM promotion
WHERE date_start <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
AND date_end >= CURDATE()
AND city IN ('','Oslo')
AND fk_countryID = 'NO'
order by date_end ASC
```